# XServer Error could not create lock file

Tags: xorg, xserver

I have tried to create a config file for my xserver with X -configure in the root shell (started ubuntu 14.04 in the save mode and selected root shell).
But it puts out this Error:

**(EE)
Fatal server error: 
(EE) Could not create lock file int /tmp/.tX0-lock
(EE)
(EE)
 Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help
(EE)**

Comment: This can be a result of several problems including a full or faulty hard drive. For example http://askubuntu.com/questions/23353/ubuntu-boots-into-terminal . It could also be a permissions problem if you changed permissions or ownership of system files such at /tmp

Comment: Sorry it was actually **/tmp/.tX0-lock** I'll correct that immediatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you dropped to a root shell from the Ubuntu *recovery mode*, then the filesystem is mounted in read-only mode by default. You will probably need to re-mount with read-write permissions in order to allow `X -configure` to write the xorg.conf file:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

(note: there is no space between the `remount` and `rw` options - just a comma). Then try the `X -configure` command again.