# How can I unlock /tmp/.tX0-lock

Tags: 16.04, xserver

I updated to 16.04 from 14.04.3. Since then I have experienced an increasingly unstable OS.

When I boot up the process gives me a terminal. When I use `startx`, I get the following error:

```
Fatal Server Error: Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock. Go to X.org Foundation for help
```

No one is home at X.org. The pile of X System docs I have reviewed describe processes that appear to happen after whatever file is locked.

A later error message in the process says:

```
xinit: giving up xinit; unable to connect to X server;Connection refused. xinit: server error
Xauth: error in locking authority file /home/robert/.Xauthority
```

How do I fix this, or where do I look to find out how to?

Answer (score 5):

> error in locking authority file /home/robert/.Xauthority

means that that file does not have the correct permissions.

Do a `ls -l /home/robert/.Xauthority` and verify it looks like this up the the 2nd "robert":

```
-rw------- 1 robert robert 57 sep  4 08:02 .Xauthority
```

---

You can set user and group with ...

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/robert/.Xauthority
```

And the permissions with ...

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/robert/.Xauthority
```

It is possible that there is an underlying problem though and that this is just a symptom.

---

> Fatal Server Error: sCould not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock. Go to X.org Foundation for help

can have a lot of reasons. It could be due to the other error above so when you fix that and this goes away fine. But it can also indicate a faulty hard disk, or a wrongly mounted `/tmp`.

Do have a look at [Ubuntu boots into terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23353/ubuntu-boots-into-terminal) and [XServer Error could not create lock file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514215/xserver-error-could-not-create-lock-file)

Comment: By the way, the listing came back